Why does a IRFP460 turning off an LED Strip but a IRLZ44N or IRL540N can't?
I am dimming a LED strip using a Raspberry Pi using a MOSFET with this circuit:

When I use an IRFP460 MOSFET I can completely switch it off, but due to the 3.3v of the Raspberry Pi GPIO, I can't fully turn max brightness. So I replaced the MOSFET with IRLZ44N, and then IRL540N. Only when I use the IRFP460 I can fully turn off the LED lights. As I'm a newbie, I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why I can't fully turn off the LEDs when using IRLZ44N or IRL540N.
As other posts mention about having the Drain/Source switched, I tried both combinations. So that shouldn't be it. Moreover, I tried 2 MOSFETs of each type to discard faulty ones.
My LED Strip consumes (as measured by the connection to the MOSFET) 42mA and 17V.

If you had the drain and gate switched, that would have destroyed the MOSFET, especially the IRL540 and IRLZ44, which have pretty low maximum gate voltage ratings. (Even the IRFP640 is only rated for a maximum of 20 V, but 24 V for a short time might not kill it completely.) After doing that, the FET wouldn't be able to turn off anything no matter how you connected it.

If instead of connecting to the GPIO, you connect the input directly to ground, are the LEDs completely extinguished?

Apologies, I did change the Drain/Source not the Drain/Gate. I corrected it in the question. Thanks for spotting it out! Anyway, all MOSFETs work in the end, as in I can change the brightness of the LEDs with them.

@SimonFitch I'll try and report back

What kind of LED strip is it? You should use a resistor paralleled with the strip to "stop" current.

The IRLZ44 is specified for 50A loads, and your load (0.042A) isn't
anywhere near that.   The use of a low-power switch FET will help,
or you could use a bipolar NPN transistor instead of a FET.
The
OFF state of a BS107KL (NMOS) is in the nano amperes range, and it'll handle the current and voltages you need.

There's no problem with using a high-current MOSFET where a low-current one will do. The IRLZ44 has more than low enough leakage unless the load is still visibly on at 25 μA--less, even, because the voltage is much lower.
